# Let's get critical: Feb 2013 Site Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Anime and Manga - Stack Exchange](http://anime.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Evaluation review queue](https://anime.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Comment: From the discussion below my answer, I would request that we get more clarity from SE on whether the Site Evaluation looks for searchability or quality (or both?). I *think* it should be both, but the instructions during the review are confusing. Perhaps a topic for our next chat cast.

Comment: @Deidara-senpai I think it wants both, but I think it's difficult to rate both at once sometimes. Yes, the perfect question would be excellent in both quality and searchability, and the worst question would be terrible in both quality and searchability, but as seen below, sometimes a great question is hard to search for. I'm sure the opposite can happen as well.

Answer (score 7):

[Is the Hyuuga main family's juinjutsu a Swastika?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/864/is-the-hyga-main-familys-juinjutsu-a-swastika)

It is difficult to Google this question, and I suspect that it is because of the "ū" symbol in the title.

When I searched for *hyuga juinjutsu swastika*, there was an anime SE result on the second page, but it was actually for [a list of new questions](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions?page=4&sort=newest) instead of the question itself. When I searched for *hyuuga juinjutsu swastika*, I found many other sites' explanations, but anime SE was nowhere to be found until page four where it linked to the same list of new questions again.

Yes, if I search *hyūga juinjutsu swastika*, the actual question is the very first result. But how many people are going to go to the effort of finding this special symbol just to Google a quick question about an anime series?

I suggest that we try to avoid using "special symbols" in romanization in order to increase search hits.

Comment: Good suggestion, I would actually suggest taking it one step further as mentioned in my other answer. (I did do the Evaluation before I read this post, by the way.)

Comment: That question is problematic. We may want to reword it to include "Nazi connection" or something. It'll probably make it more googleable.

Answer (score 4):

Anyone doing the site evaluation should be willing to put in some effort and time. Copy pasting the question title as is into Google search box doesn't help much. It rarely happens that people post the same question using the exact same phrase on other sites, so that way our question will always end up on the front page, if not at the top of the list.

Taking the example given in another answer "Is the Hyūga main family's juinjutsu a Swastika?", the words Hyūga and juinjutsu are not used as often, so naturally our question takes the top spot. When I instead searched for "Is the Hyuuga clan's symbol a swastika?", I did not find our question on the first **20** pages. Moreover, although the answer written here is great, I found better answers on other sites listed on page 1 (Better is subjective and no offense meant to the person who posted that answer here). Hence, my rating for this question was "Needs Improvement".

Remember that the purpose of site evaluation is to measure how likely people are to come to our site through search engines. We should therefore search the phrase that an average person would enter into the search engine. Simply asking our question to the search engine, and then throwing a party when it comes up on top (that is, rating as "Excellent") doesn't really serve any purpose.

**Edit** Note that a "Needs Improvement" rating does not necessarily mean that the question or answer is bad. The way the Site Evaluation criteria is currently implemented, it seems the rating includes both quality and searchability.

Comment: I agree with what you say but at the same time, I think the descriptions provided by SE as a whole are somewhat confusing. Are we rating the quality of the questions/answers or how easy they are to Google? It is hard to Google that Hyuuga question, but the question and answer are both great. I feel like it would be easier if SE had two separate ratings: one for quality, and one for searchability.

Comment: I totally agree. I too found it a bit odd that quality and searchability are bundled into one, so it looks like we need to rate it for both together.

Comment: If you google for "Naruto Swastika" then we're pretty high on the front page, though admittedly not high enough that we'd beat out the other links. But since the question title doesn't have "Hyuuga" we don't make it on to google at all there. Similarly if you google for "Fairy Law vs Fairy Glitter" or "One Piece Currency" we're on the first page.

Comment: Also feel free to link me to which sites you think had better answers. My answer had everything that I knew off the top of my head, but if there are other places with more information I can include that as well.